# Can a plane turn around like on this photo?

Tags: maneuver, plane-spotting, pic

I've never seen a plane do such a maneuver, have you?

Is this photo just a hoax?

[image: enter image description pls]

Comment: Probably not real - that would need a pretty steep bank angle, so the contrails in the turn would appear closer together, or merge even.

Comment: @CrossRoads Agreed, the only way that can be done is if the plane is not leveled at all before and after the turn and keeping the exactly bank. in addition it must be slow and at high altitude meaning it's already loosing altitude

Answer (score 4):

hoax, totally. that plane is travelling at about 550MPH and the forces required to turn it 180 degrees with a radius of ~two wingspans would destroy the plane and kill everybody in it.

Comment: We cannot know how much fast it's going, from that perspective we cannot tell it's going "slow" and even stalling due to it. But i agreed it looks like fake because the contrails in the turn looks too much parallel

Comment: @jean From the contrails we know a minimum flight altitude. From the wing loading we know the minimum airspeed at that altitude. It's a bit less than 550 mph, but the possible turn radius is still kilometers wide.

Comment: @PeterKämpf Yeah, unless it's falling like a brick and from that perspective we cannot tell =)

Comment: @jean even then the contrails would look very different - not a semicircle but a very long half ellipse.